# How to declare an iterator for a vector of a generic type?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

I have problems declaring an iterator for a vector that is of a generic type.
Code as follows:

```
    template <class T> void print(const vector<T>& V )
    {
      vector<T>::const_iterator i;
    }
```

The following returns an error expected ; before 'i'.
There will be no error if I specifically stated `vector<int>::const_iterator i;`

Is there a way to solve the problem?

Comment: `typename vector<T>::const_iterator i;`

Answer (score 3):

`const_iterator` is a dependent name in this context, since it depends on `T`. It is assumed not to name a type unless you explicitly qualify it with the `typename` keyword.

```
template <class T> void print(const vector<T>& V )
{
  typename vector<T>::const_iterator i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this:

```
  template <class T> void print(const vector<T>& V )
    {
      //T is a dependant type so needs typename
      typename vector<T>::const_iterator i;
    }
```